# django model create does not work

Tags: python, django, django-models

I added a new model to my app named SocialProfile, which is responsible for keeping social-related properties of a user which has a one-to-one relationship with UserProfile model. This is the SocialProfile model in models.py:

```
class SocialProfile(models.Model):
    profile = models.OneToOneField('UserProfile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    facebook_profiles = models.ManyToManyField('FacebookContact', related_name='synced_profiles', blank=True)
    google_profiles = models.ManyToManyField('GoogleContact', related_name='synced_profiles', blank=True)
    hash = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            hash = gen_hash(self.id, 30)
            while SocialProfile.objects.filter(hash=hash).exists():
                hash = gen_hash(self.id, 30)
            self.hash = hash

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.profile)
```

Right now, I keep a record for synced facebook & google profiles. Now, the problem is that creating new objects does not actually add any record in the database. I cannot create instances with scripts or admin. In case of scripts, the following runs without errors but no record is created:

```
for profile in UserProfile.objects.all():
    sp = SocialProfile.objects.create(profile=profile)
    print(profile, sp)

SocialProfile.objects.count()
```

The prints are done, and look correct and the count() returns 0. I try creating objects in admin, but I get the following error:

```
"{{socialprofile object}}" needs to have a value for field "socialprofile" before 
this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

I think that is another problem, because if I comment the Many-to-Many relationships, it is done, without error (still no new records). I mentioned it just if it might help.

I have checked the database, the tables are there, no new migrations are detected either.

Any help and idea about what could be the problem would be appreciated!

Comment: I even deleted my database and created a new database, still the same happened.

Comment: Can you post your User Profile model as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've overwritten the save method so that it never actually saves anything. You need to call the superclass method at the end:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:
        ...
    return super(SocialProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks, such a rookie mistake!

Comment: Thanks a lot, i accidentally commented out the save method.